# Inheritance with this and super

Tags: java, inheritance

Working in Java.

I have an abstract class as such:

```
public abstract class Foo {
    protected Logger log = null;

    // other stuff

    public boolean isLoggerSet() {
        return (this.log != null) ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Now i extend this class as such:

```
public class Bar extends Foo {
    public Bar() {
        this.log = Logger.getLogger(Bar.class);
    }

    public void someMethod(String[] args) {
        Bar b = new Bar();
        if(b.isLoggerSet()) {
            // do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

`The question:` Is my Bar.class actually referring to the `super.log` even though I call `this.log` since Bar does not have it's own local variable called `log`? Or would the correct way to implement the `isLoggerSet()` method be to make it abstract and force Bar.class to implement it itself on it's local copy of `log` since it's been extended?

Basically I have to say `this.log` in my Foo class because, it refers to itself. But in Bar class I want to be able to null check `log`, should I instead be using `super.log =` in Bar.class?

Comment: There's only one `log` property. In general you don't need instances to have their own logger, though; typically they're `public static final`.

Comment: `if(this.isLoggerSet())` won't compile in static context.

Comment: Does this still apply if it's not a `Logger` that I'm trying to `null check`? I just used the logger because that was the example at hand.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad sorry, it was a quick example i typed out, pulled from my codebase... i'll fix that now.

Comment: someMethod can only be called on an instance of Bar. Inside someMethod a new instance of Bar is created. So there must be two instances of Bar in this example which I think is not what you intended. The LOG example is making the question unclear because Loggers are usually static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not set your Logger to `static`, but instead to `protected`.
Whether you use `super` or `this`, they point to the exact same variable in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If there's only one attribute called `log` in the class hierarchy, it doesn't matter if you say `this.log` or `super.log`, it'll refer to the same one - the only one!

Answer (score 2):

`this.log` is the same `super.log`. There is only one variable because `log` is inherited from Foo.
The only one change is required: `this.isLoggerSet()` should be replaced by `b.isLoggerSet()`
You cannot call non static method inside static method

Answer (score 2):

Classes are blueprints for making objects. In your case, the blueprint for "Bar" adds on to the blueprint defined in "Foo" (which adds to the blueprint defined in "Object").

Don't let the baseclass confuse you: *conceptually* here the compiler pulls all the base classes up into one top-level combined class (ignoring the "Object" base):

```
public class Bar {

    protected Logger log = null;

    public boolean isLoggerSet() {
        return (log != null) ? true : false;
    }

    public Bar() {
        log = Logger.getLogger(Bar.class);
    }

    public void someMethod(String [] args) {
        Bar b = new Bar();
        if(b.isLoggerSet()) {
            // do some stuff
        }
    }

}
```

You would exercise your code like this:

```
Bar x = new Bar();
x.isLoggerSet(); // Returns true since Bar() constructor just set it
x.someMethod(args);
```

The first line creates a new object of type "Bar" in memory. This object has a single pointer to a "Logger" object that gets set in the Bar constructor on the first line with "new Bar()".

The next line checks "isLoggerSet". Assuming that "getLogger" returns a live object then the "isLoggerSet" will always return true.

The last line calls "x.someMethod(args)". This method creates a new "Bar" object (whose constructor sets its "log" pointer). Thus the "b.isLoggerSet()" will pass here too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly modified example:

```
public abstract class Foo {
    protected String name;

    public Foo() {
        name = "Mr. Foo";
    }
}

public class Bar extends Foo {
    protected String name;

    public Bar() {
        name = "Mr. Bar";
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        System.out.println("this.name=" + this.name);
        System.out.println("super.name=" + super.name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
this.name=Mr. Bar
super.name=Mr. Foo
```

So there are two variables called 'name', one in each class. To access the one in the superclass from within the subclass you need to use 'super.name'.

When creating a Bar() Java checks for a super(...) call to a constructor of the superclass as the first line of the constructor. If it is not there (like above) then 'super();' is invisibly inserted as the first line of the constructor. So I could have written:

```
....
    public Bar() {
        super();
        name = "Mr. Bar";
    }
....
```

With the same result. However, this is not necessary, Java inserts a super call to the default constructor for you if you don't call a super constructor yourself. In this way constructor chaining is enforced.

If you want to call a super constructor yourself you could also call a non-default constructor, for example:

```
    public abstract class Foo {
        protected String name;

        public Foo() {
            name = "Mr. Foo";
        }

        public Foo(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    public class Bar extends Foo {

        public Bar() {
            super("Mr. Bar");
        }

        public void someMethod() {
            System.out.println("this.name=" + this.name);
            System.out.println("super.name=" + super.name);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Bar bar = new Bar();
            bar.someMethod();
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
this.name=Mr. Bar // refers to 'name' inherited from Foo
super.name=Mr. Bar // refers to 'name' in superclass, set by the String constructor
// so these both refer to the same variable in this example
```

Note the default constructor of Foo is not called in this last example.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, having a variable initialized in a constructor for both the abstract and the extended classes, results in two separate variables, `name` in this case?